# Visual Basic .Net, keep windows on top of other on-top windows

Tags: vb.net, taskbar, always-on-top

I have created a program that I want to show in the taskbar the whole time. It launches a few keyboard shortcuts when I press their buttons. The program works great, but the windows taskbar needs to be set to always on-top or programs will maximize over it too.

If I have both my programs and the windows taskbar set to be always on top, My program is on-top of the taskbar until I click anywhere in the taskbar, for example to activate another program.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    Me.TopMost = True

    '...
End Sub
```

I considered using a timer to activate my program once in a while, but the downside to that approach is, that if I am typing in another application and the focus is moved to my program, this is very annoying.

So my question is as follows: Is there a way I can interact with the taskbar so my program is always ontop of it, regardless of anything else, or is it possible to periodically restore the on-top status so my program becomes on-top of the taskbar again without the focus going to my program?

I prefer that my program is always ontop if the taskbar, and clicking the taskbar does not temporarily make my program invisible. For example, if I can set the z-order of my application to a higher level than the taskbar, that would be best. If otherwise I can somehow spawn my program as part of the taskbar, that would also work.

PS: I have enabled the search bar in the taskbar and my program is supposed to cover it entirely. I don't use the search bar and it gives me a dedicated space without worrying covering any open programs.

PS2: This is just for me, no need to worry about anyone who has different preferences. My goal is to optimize my workflow, so the least hastle I have daily, the better.

This is what it looks like when the app runs, but clicking the taskbar makes the window invisible.:
[image]

So... How can I make sure my program stays on-top of the taskbar, even if I click somewhere in the taskbar?

Comment: what do u mean 
>on top of task bar
???

Comment: @zackraiyan see the image I added: My application is physically positioned above the taskbar. I've set always on-top enabled on my application, but the taskbar has this too. If I click on the taskbar itself, my app is moved behind the taskbar.

Comment: Also, to whoever downvoted me: Please explain why this is worth a downvote?

Comment: Instead of trying to compete with the always-on-top functionality of the taskbar, maybe creating a taskbar thumbnail toolbar is a better option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491726(v=vs.85).aspx or some other options are to "dock" it right above the taskbar or even hide it off screen and show it when you mouse moves to the screen edges.

Comment: Hi @ChaseRocker, thanks for helping by thinking outside of the box. If I can create a toolbar that I can dock into the taskbar, that would be the best, but I was unable to find any source or explaination on how to do that. A thumbnail toolbar would not be on the screen the whole time, so it takes much more time to press these buttons. As for hiding them, that would mean I have to move the position and I really like to keep it there. (otherwise the taskbar will still be in front of it.

Comment: @ChaseRocker but you did gave me an idea. I may be able to get the x and y position of the mouse and when it is over my window, even if it is below the taskbar, it could still activate and show it. It would be very ugly, but it would at least be a workaround that is better than the one I have now: not have the taskbar on-top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was pretty simple.

I was afraid of side-effects, but the solution I applied works perfectly.

I added a timer, enabled it, and every tick it simply does:

```
me.Topmost = true
```

If I now click the taskbar, the program is obviously pushed to the back, but every 100ms when the timer ticks, the program is automatically put back on top without the app actually receiving focus.